# $y^2 = f(x)$ has p solutions in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

Im am searching for the following problem, but I have no idea how to start with it. Can someone help me with this?

Let $p$ be a prime congruent to $3 \mod 4$ and let $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ be such that $f(-x) = -f(x)$
for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Show that the equation $y^2 = f(x)$ has precisely $p$ solutions $(x, y)$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Hint: For how many values of $x$ is $f(x)$ a quadratic residue?